# Probabilities and Binomial Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a binomial random variable with $n = 25$ and $p = 0.7$. Use Excel or Minitab to find the following. Please give the answers to five decimal places.

$$P(X = 16) = ?$$

I used the excel binomial distribution function and it is saying my answer is wrong. I put $0.67693$, and was wondering if it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is asking for greater than or equal to $16$, the answer would be

$1-P(X<=15)=1-binocdf(15,25,0.7)=0.810563976495052$

where I have used GNU Octave's binomial CDF function called $binocdf()$.

Comment: This was correct, thank you!

Comment: Why is it the compliment of less than fifteen?

Comment: It is the complement of less than *or equal to* $15$, as you want the probability of $X$ being $16$ or more.

Answer (score 0):

We should calculate $C_{25}^{16}0.7^{16} 0.3^9$, right?

wolfram gives http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B25%2C16%5D*%280.7%5E16%29*%280.3%5E9%29

the answer is 0.1336358513921865558356925

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried several different things including this answer but the online homework is saying this is incorrect. Im starting to wonder if its an error with the program? The question is asking for greater than or equal to 16

Comment: If I am the quesion designer, I may check the use of poission distribution to approximate binomial distribution. This is just my guess.

Comment: Jake: In your problem statement you asked for the probability that X=16.  In the comment above you say the question is asking for the probability that X >= 16.  Which is it?  This is probably the cause of your confusion.

Comment: The question asks for greater than or equal to 16. I think it might have been corrected by the site after I posted it.